# Mongodb aggregate with lookup fields from left collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have below query

```
db.firstcollection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      organization: "org 1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "secondcollection",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "secondcollection"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$secondcollection"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: "$secondcollection.id",
      col1: "ddd",
      "emailAddress": "$secondcollection.emailAddress",
      "fullName": "$secondcollection.fullName"
    }
  }
])
```

Using alias secondcollection we can retrieve fileds of second collection, but how can we retrieve fields from first collection

Thanks

Comment: your question is ambiguous... can you please clarify it...

Comment: question edited.

Comment: in `$project`, specify field names of first collection without any prefix. for example `"first_collection_name" : "first_collection_name"`

Comment: Please post your sample collection and ouput please'